# Is there a way to do the action in a for loop after a certain period of time (not instantly)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am making a function that scans a Grid and every square's neighbours, and changes certain values (dead/live) in the grid. The current problem I have is: The modifications are made to certain parts of the grid BEFORE the whole scan is done. This means the scan will come out wrong. Here is the code to the function:

```
 public void GridScan(Vector3 worldposition, int range)
    {
        GetXY(worldposition, out int originx, out int originy);
        for (int x = 0; x < range; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < range; y++)
            {
                Debug.Log(GetValue(originx + x, originy + y));
                if ((GetValue(originx + x, originy + y)) == 100)
                {
                    if (Neighbours(GetWorldPosition(x, y), 2) < 2)
                    {
                        SetValue(x, y, 0);
                    }
                    if (Neighbours(GetWorldPosition(x, y), 2) > 3)
                    {
                        SetValue(x, y, 0);
                    }
                }

                if ((GetValue(originx + x, originy + y)) == 0)
                {
                    if (Neighbours(GetWorldPosition(x, y), 2) == 3)
                    {
                        SetValue(x, y, 100);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Bit of context:
"GetXY" simply converts the vector3 worldposition to coordinates of the graph.

The two for loops scan through the whole graph from the origin, going from (0,0)-(range,0) then (0,1)-(range,1) etc.

"SetValue" & "GetValue" do exactly what they say with an input of the two coordinates.

"Neighbours" Scans for the number of neighbours with a certain value neighbours.

"GetWorldPosition" coverts the x,y coordinates into a vector 3 that "Neighbours" can use.

**Is there anyway to do the "SetValue" after the for loops are done? Can I Make an instance of the grid perhaps (if so, how?)? Would those methods solve my problem? This is one of my first projects so bare with me.**

Comment: If I am understanding your problem correctly. Just create a list of all the changes you are about to make, and complete them after the loop. `List<(int x, int y, int funkyNumber)>`

Comment: @MichaelRandall Oh, so just list them inside the if statments and then just do SetValue to the list afterwards?

Comment: Yeah even if the items can mutate the result more than once, they are played in order, so all good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a list of all the changes you are about to make, and complete them after the loop in order. `List<(int x, int y, int funkyNumber)>`

<sub>***Note** I am not sure if you can use ValueTuples in unity these days. If you can't, you could just create your own struct*</sub>

**Example**

```
var list = new List<(int x, int y, int funkyNumber)>();

GetXY(worldposition, out int originx, out int originy);
for (int x = 0; x < range; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < range; y++)
   {
      Debug.Log(GetValue(originx + x, originy + y));
      if ((GetValue(originx + x, originy + y)) == 100)
      {
         if (Neighbours(GetWorldPosition(x, y), 2) < 2)
            list.Add((x, y, 0));
         if (Neighbours(GetWorldPosition(x, y), 2) > 3)
            list.Add((x, y, 0));
      }

      if ((GetValue(originx + x, originy + y)) == 0)
      {
         if (Neighbours(GetWorldPosition(x, y), 2) == 3)
            list.Add((x, y, 100));
      }
   }
}

foreach (var item in list)
   SetValue(item.x,item.y,item.funkyNumber)
```

Comment: It works! I cannot thank you enough. Its very nice that its simple so i actually can understand what is going on.